# Exporting PL/SQL Packages Through TTS

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-administration, tablespace

I am very new to dba tasks. I can export PL/SQL packages, functions, procedures from one database to another with expdp and impdp. But I need to export these objects(functions, procedures) by Transporting the tablespace(TTS) . I searched in different threads but didn't get any help. I heard there is a way of exporting packages through TTS (even though I read in many forums that "packages cannot be exported through TTS" ). But how? I already tried TTS but packages were not exported,only tables were exported.

Comment: Why is a package different from any other object type?  Have you tried it?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: @OldProgrammer As I have understood, Packages depend on System Tablespace as well and System tablespace cannot be transported. But I heard there is a way.

Comment: @Joseph  I am using 11g..

Comment: Why have you decided that you need to use one particular tool (transportable tablespaces) to accomplish a task rather than another, seemingly much more logical tool (expdp) that you know correctly accomplishes the task?  Particularly when using transportable tablespaces requires a metadata export anyway.

Comment: @JustinCave I have to transfer GBs of info from the server, so I have decided to use TTS.

Comment: Which is great for transferring data.  Why not use an export to transfer code?  Particularly when you need a metadata export to transport the tablespace.  Why do you need to use transportable tablespaces to transfer the code?

Comment: @JustinCave I think it's fast and efficient if I exported all objects (tables , procedures, packages, etc) through TTS. The next reason is I want to learn how to export packages through TTS as I am new to Database Administration.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Oracle 10 g or later, then you can use the INCLUDE parameter of the Data Pump to export packages, as below:

```
expdp system/password@db10g directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=DB10G.dmp logfile=expdpDB10G.log INCLUDE=PACKAGE
```

**References**:

[Oracle Data Pump (expdp and impdp) in Oracle Database 10g on ORACLE-BASE](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php)

[Parameters Available in Export's Command-Line Mode on Oracle® Database Utilities](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm#i1006293)

Comment: I have already done this. It worked. But I need to transfer packages through TTS